# Convert number to date in java

Tags: java, parsing, date

I communicate with a server and I get this type of JSON response:

`WeekEndingDate=/Date(1428638400000-0400)/`

The function behind getting this number from a date is :

```
function ParseJSONDate(value) {
   return JSON.parseWithDate(JSON.stringify(value)).format("mm/dd/yyyy");
}
```

My question is: how do I get back the date, in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` from that value `(/Date(1428638400000-0400)/)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i don't make a mistake the string "1428638400000-0400" represents two information :

- 1428638400000 : the number of milliseconds
- 0400 : the hour

So after splitting by '-'. You could create a date with :

```
Date d = new Date ("1428638400000");
```

After that you could print it with a DateFormat.
Hope this help

Comment: `Date(String)` is deprecated.

Comment: you could convert the "1428638400000" to long

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat$parse()` method in order to get a `Date` object, then reformat it with the wanted format. The parsing format is of the form:

- `ssssssssss` (10 's'): date-time in seconds
- `SSS`: milliseconds
- `Z`: time zone, which is "-0400" in the example.

---

```
String input = "1428638400000-0400";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ssssssssssSSSZ");
Date myDate = inputFormat.parse(input);

SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String myDateAsString = outputFormat.format(myDate);
System.out.println(myDateAsString);

=> 04/10/2015
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this below code...

```
public static Date convertMillisecondsTodate(int givenMilliseconds) {
    String convertedMilliSeconds = Integer.toString(givenMilliseconds)
            .concat("000");

    /* DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); */

    long milliSeconds = Long.parseLong(convertedMilliSeconds);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
    Date date = new Date(milliSeconds);

    return date;

}
```